# Как в Objective-C изменить стандартный переход в Storyboard из одной сцены к другой

Tags: ipad, objective-c, ios, iphone

В моем проекте пока стоит стандартный переход от сцены к сцене при push. 
А мне задумалось сделать что-то поинтереснее.
Как это можно реализовать?

У меня в основе стоит Navigation Controller.
И кстати когда я пытался сделать переход типа modal - симулятор прекращал работу приложения.

Ну и хочется сделать что-то поинтереснее чем четыре модальных варианта.

Заранее благодарен за помощь )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот вам история в картинках:

1) Начинаете с того, что добавляете новый класс:

[image: New class]

2) Делаете его подклассом UIStoryboardSegue, называете его, как хотите:

[image: UIStoryboardSegue]

3) Добавляете в получившийся .m-метод метод perform:

```
#import "CustomSegue.h"

#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation CustomSegue

- (void)perform {
    UIViewController *sourceViewController = (UIViewController *)[self sourceViewController];
    UIViewController *destinationController = (UIViewController *)[self destinationViewController];

    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = .25;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop; //kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom

    [sourceViewController.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition
                                                                forKey:kCATransition];

    [sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:NO];
}

@end
```

[image: Perform method]

4) Идете в Storyboard. Удерживая Control, тянете от одного контроллера к другому мышь - отпускаете, выбираете `custom`:

[image: Connect two controllers using custom segue]

5) Указываете в свойствах этой Segue, что её класс - CustomSegue.

[image: Setting segue properties]

6) Добавляете в проект фреймворк QuartzCore (если он ещё не добавлен).

[image: QuartzCore]

7) Пробуете разные способы анимации через изменение опций в методе `perform`.

Удачи!

Comment: и надо еще добавить в проэкт фреймворк quartzcore

Comment: Да, верно. Сейчас обновлю ответ.

Comment: @MrPepper, обновил. Спасибо за добавление!

Comment: СПАСИБО ВСЕ ГУТ - ОСВАИВАЮ!